# How to add hashes to itself and remove duplicates in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, duplicates

I have a hash:

```
h = { ["alpha"]=>[{  "bit"=>"100", "colour"=>"red"},
                  {   "id"=>"100", "colour"=>"red"},
                  { "value"=>"65", "colour"=>"red"}],
      ["beta"] =>[{   "id"=>"070", "colour"=>"black"},
                  {"value"=>"338", "colour"=>"black"}]
}
```

I want to add hashes in values to itself and delete duplicated pairs from every item to get

```
h = { ["alpha"]=>[{"bit"=>"100", "id"=>"100", "value"=>"65", "colour"=>"red"}],
      ["beta"] =>[{"id"=>"070", "value"=>"338", "colour"=>"black"}]
}
```

I tried so far converting hashes to array and remove duplicates but how to convert array to hash again? And I also think it is not effective and elegant solution. Any other ideas?

Comment: Why do you need arrays if they all have 1 element only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for **Ruby >= 2.4.0** - method [`#transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_valueshttps://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_valueshttps://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) with methods [`#inject`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject) and [`#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge)

```
h.transform_values { |v| v.inject(:merge) }
```

For lower versions:

```
h.map { |k, v| [k, v.inject(:merge)] }.to_h
```

Comment: h.transform_values*

Comment: Thanks, it works :) But could you explain to me step by step that code? I've used the code for lower version.

Comment: @mia102aim you can follow links and investigate how it works. It would be more useful then I explain every this method.

Answer (score 0):

Longer version, step by step, can look like that:

```
    h.inject({}) { |result, (key, value)| 
      result[key] = value.inject({}){ |value_result, value_elem| 
            value_result.merge! value_elem; value_result
      }; result 
   }
```

It basically transforms array of hashes (in each value) into single hash, containing unique values. But be aware - if you will have hash like that:

```
h = {
"alpha"=>[{"bit"=>"100", "colour"=>"red"}, {"id"=>"100", "colour"=>"blue"}]
}
```

with two different values for key "colour", the output will look like that:

```
{"alpha"=>{"bit"=>"100", "colour"=>"blue", "id"=>"100"}}
```

This is how #merge method works.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is all keys.

```
h.merge(h) { |_,arr| arr.reduce(&:merge) }
  #=> {["alpha"]=>{"bit"=>"100", "colour"=>"red", "id"=>"100", "value"=>"65"},
  #    ["beta"] =>{"id"=>"070", "colour"=>"black", "value"=>"338"}}
```